# Nativescript angular2 reuse componentin other component

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am developing nativescript app with angular2 and typescript.

I have imageComponentA, pageComponentB, pageComponentC and their modules(imageModuleA, pageModuleB, pageModuleC).

pageModuleB, pageModuleC are pages in route.
imageModuleA is image (just `<Image src="src"></Image>`).

If i declare imageModuleA inside pageModuleB like below.
App displays imageModuleA without problem.

Something like this

```
main.ts
    import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
    platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

app.module  (top module) 
    NgModule
        imports [pageModuleB, pageModuleC] 

pageModuleB
    NgModule
        declarations [imageComponentA] 
pageModuleC
    NgModule
        declarations []
```

Then I want to reuse imageModuleA in pageModuleC too.
If i declare imageModuleA in module of pageModuleC it says 'imageComponentA is part of declaration of 2 modules. Conside moving higher module'

Then i moved imageModuleA one layer up to app.module and removes declarion from pageModuleB, pageModuleC

```
app.module (top module) 
    NgModule
        imports [pageModuleB, pageModuleC] 
        declarations [imageComponentA]

pageModuleB
    NgModule
        declarations [] 
pageModuleC
    NgModule
        declarations []
```

it compiles and runs the app but imageComponentA is not displaying.

I thought it is simple angular2 NgModule thing.
What am i doing wrong?

---

Update 1

I also tried importing imageModuleA in app.module

```
main.ts
    import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
    platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);

app.module (top module) 
    NgModule
        imports [imageModuleA, pageModuleB, pageModuleC] 
        declarations []

pageModuleB
    NgModule
        declarations [] 
pageModuleC
    NgModule
        declarations []
```

Comment: Perhaps to be able to access modules you should declare them inside the `main.ts` file as it has been shown here - https://github.com/tsonevn/NGModalView_question38835363/blob/master/app/main.ts

Comment: I am using this library as upstream. https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries

It imports AppModule inside main.ts

Comment: @NikolayTsonev updated the question

Comment: Try to add in the `declarations` the three Components: `imageComponentA`, `pageComponentB`, `pageComponentC` the  app.module. Regarding to that it will help if you could provide sample project.

Comment: I created sample project here 

https://github.com/matart15/sample-Grossery/commit/cad9c5fa093a84bcb25c27b207ec47eff1a58e73

If I comment out this line 
https://github.com/matart15/sample-Grossery/commit/cad9c5fa093a84bcb25c27b207ec47eff1a58e73#diff-c9ea3387ef7816bba73a6baea4c24e38R27

and comment in this line
https://github.com/matart15/sample-Grossery/commit/cad9c5fa093a84bcb25c27b207ec47eff1a58e73#diff-4151fe1cea128af6e351c4feb04bedcdR16

image appears.

Comment: Ok I solved it @NgModule exports[] was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it work. I was missing export in NgModule

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep simple for this start, you dont need to create lot of modules, just the main app module is okay, add your 3 components to the app module declaration array.

See the same code below and the screenshot of the output

[image: Screenshot]

```js
// this import should be first in order to load some required settings (like globals and reflect-metadata)
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule, Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app-image",
    template: `<Image width="250" src="https://d2odgkulk9w7if.cloudfront.net/images/default-source/home/ns-angular-javascript-typescript.png?sfvrsn=2"></Image>
    `,
})
export class ImageComponent {
}

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
    <StackLayout>
    <app-image></app-image>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"></Label>

    <Button text="TAP" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>

    <Label [text]="message" class="message" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
    public counter: number = 16;

    public get message(): string {
        if (this.counter > 0) {
            return this.counter + " taps left";
        } else {
            return "Hoorraaay! \nYou are ready to start building!";
        }
    }

    public onTap() {
        this.counter--;
    }
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, ImageComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [NativeScriptModule],
})
class AppComponentModule {}

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.
I agree with `keep simple for the start`.

I managed to get it work. I was missing export in NgModule